# Renaming a word in multiple files

Tags: texstudio

I have a number of files:

- main.tex
- chapter1.tex
- chapter2.tex
- chapter3.tex
- chapter4.tex

The chapter files are linked in main.tex with the \input command.

In main.tex I define a named listing called *sampletext* that is also used throughout the chapters. I would like to rename this to *examplecode* in the main.tex and all the chapter files. How can I do this? I am using TexStudio 2.1.1.0 on Windows.

Comment: Seems like more of a [stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60034/1075876) to me. I'd suggest using using `sed`: `sed -i.bak 's/sampletext/examplecode/g' *.tex`, but, for Windows, the challenge may be getting a working version of `sed` up and running. (Not on Windows myself, however.)

Comment: What I'd do is wipe Windows and install an OS which provides `sed`. However, you may consider that solution overkill.

Comment: Even if your editor provided that option, can you image the havoc it would cause with a mistake?

Comment: @cfr GOW provides `sed` and many other goodies on Windows: it's about 4 Mb so not a difficult install :)

Comment: @JosephWright On networked machines, it is an impossible install :(.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace in multiple files in TeXstudio using the extended search:

1. Search for the string to replace.
2. Open the extended search using the `[+]` button in the search panel.
3. Switch the scope from "Current Doc" to "Project".
4. The search results list will be updated and show all matches.
5. Type the new text in the field "Replace By" and press "Replace All"

[image]

Note: You can also deselect individual occurences using the checkboxes if you want to replace only a subset of all occurences.

Comment: If this is Texstudio (mentioned in OP), maybe you could make that a little clearer.